# X11: Convert Pixel value to RGB

Tags: c, x11, rgb, pixel, xlib

I'm relatively new to X11 and extending an X11 application. I need to convert a color in a variable of type `Pixel` into its RGB components.
My understanding is that this depends on the application's visual. For *TrueColor* and *DirectColor* visuals I can look at the `XVisualInfo` and use the `bits_per_rgb` and `{red,green,blue}_mask` members.

But what to do for *PseudoColor* or other visuals? What I need is a function such as

```
void PixelToRGB(Pixel p, XVisualInfo *v, uint16_t *r, uint16_t *g, uint16_t *b)
```

I'm reading Xlib programming manuals but could not yet find information how to implement such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done Xlib programming so this is educated guesswork, but you should be able to get the `ColorMap` from the `XWindowAttributes` of the window in question, and the pixel value will be an index into the color map. Apparently the lookup is done by stuffing the pixel into an `XColor` and calling `XQueryColor` with it, which will populate the `XColor`'s `red`, `green`, and `blue` fields. I believe this is also supposed to be done even with `DirectColor` and `TrueColor` visuals, as the colormap can contain things like gamma corrections, and perhaps odder things (weird color-cycling effects?) in the case of a `DirectColor` visual.

Comment: `XQueryColor` is exactly what I need. Thanks!